# Simple Linear Regression Prediction Algorithm in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, algorithm, linear-regression, prediction

I am trying to do a simple profit prediction of an organization in the future based on the past profit in JavaScript. My dataset will be the date as x-axis and the profit as y-axis. I am new to data analytics and basically I have zero knowledge in it and I not sure which prediction algorithm will be the most suitable.

I have done some researches [here](https://bl.ocks.org/proclamo/97ae6e6a64c48b8f4e87) and [here](https://github.com/luccastera/shaman) and found out that I can actually use the Linear Regression Prediction algorithm. However, from those examples, I only saw that the prediction algorithm is simply plotting a straight line based on the data to find out the regression value and it does not predict any value for the future at all.

I wonder if the algorithm mentioned above is applicable for my case?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It depends a lot on the business and how much data you have. Does the past history follow a regular linear progression? If so then a linear model would make sense. Are there ups and downs? What explains those? Is it seasonal or some other cyclical? If so you need to take those into account. Are there specific periods with huge outliers that are very uncommon? Perhaps correcting (removing) those would yield better results.

There is no one-size-fits-all solution.

Comment: The datasets will be quite small which is around 4k records and there are ups and downs. I am just wondering if the linear regression can actually perform a prediction because from what I see fromt the examples, they are only plotting a straight line based on the data presented and does not predict anything in the future at all. (I know that I might be wrong as I do not have much knowledge in this field, please correct me if I am wrong :) )That defeats the purpose as what I wanted to achieve is to get a predicted value in the future.

Comment: @guest176969 yes, deriving a linear regression can then be used to make predictions, the accuracy of which will depend on the data and applicability of formula to the data.

Comment: What I meant is based on the past data, I can plot out the regression line. But how am I supposed to extend the regression line to predict the profit in the next few years? The two examples above never show it.

Comment: @guest176969 The examples you pointed to already do exactly what you're asking for. Look at `console.log("Weight for a child 15 years old:",f(15));`

Comment: I see I see thanks so much! However, I realized one thing, if my data is going up and down crazily, the linear regression above is not predicting correctly. Is there any way to change it to become cubic regression?

Answer (score 0):

The prediction has nothing to do with JavaScript or HTML. It's just using a regression function. How to fit your function to data granted is a realm of regression analysis. You can check the [least squares method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Least_squares) to clarify your understanding.

Choosing of regression function is another issue. It's related to realm your data come from. You have to be aware of restrictions on your output so you can take a function that will fit the business logic (for example, if you have your data cyclic by a year or a day or whatever, you may wrap sin() or cos() function over another one).

There is one more method to predict. It's related to machine learning and based on artificial neural networks.  If you're interested doing this with JS, I can suggest you use [brain.js](https://github.com/BrainJS/brain.js) - the simplest library to deal with neural networks in JS.

Comment: Hey is there any way to change the reference links above to auto regression? Because AFAIK, the auto regression will actually fit as close as possible to the curve of the regression function right? Because I realized a problem, when I am using linear regression, the prediction is always either go up or down in one direction. If I am using cubic regression, the same thing, but the prediction is growing in a curve manner. Both of the prediction resulting in wrong value as my input data is always go up and down.